# Detecting a loud impulse sound

Tags: raspberry-pi, filtering, signal-processing, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to design a system on a rasp pi that can detect a loud sudden sound like a clap. I'm able to capture the input sound samples real time (using a simple python program)  but need an efficient way to run my algorithm on these online samples to indicate a spike. I'm not too familiar with filters that are used for such applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you possibly take a moving average of the rms values and if the input is above a certain threshold from that value the it will be considered a "spike"?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a circular buffer to gather the inputs

Comment: @adanot  The threshold value is something that is non-constant, therefore a spike is only relative to its past and future samples. Still your idea makes sense, in the most trivial implementation, one can look at the SecondBeforeLast, Last and Current sample and if Last > Current && Last > SecondBeforeLast, it can be considered a spike. I think this is error prone if one gets the sampling rate wrong and we could continuously miss spikes.

Answer (score 3):

1. apply a highpass, above 1 kHz seems to work reasonably well. The clap should contain mostly high frequency components.
2. compute rms, e.g. square the output of the highpass, average this over the last 100 samples to smoothe
3. normalize over some time window, e.g. the last N samples. Make sure that you make this window longer than your moving average for the rms. For your current sample, subtract the mean of this buffer and divide by the standard deviation in the buffer. This way you detect relative changes of signal to noise ratio in your window, which are independent of the current amplitude.
4. Pick a threshold SNR to declare a clap